# How to see who subscribed you to a report?

Tags: reporting, subscriber, unsubscriber

I cannot unsubscribe to a report that was setup by another user.  How can I see who set up the report?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a Report on Subscriptions which will be able to tell you who set up the subscription.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_subscription_reporting.htm&type=5